# Conditions for solution to transport equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we consider an operator 
$$
D = i \frac{d}{dx} + B(x) \colon C_U^\infty([0,\beta],\mathbb{C^n}) \to C_U^\infty([0,\beta],\mathbb{C^n})
$$
acting on smooth complex vector valued functions defined on the interval $[0,\beta]$ with the boundary condition that $f(0) = U f(\beta)$ for some $U \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. Here $B(x) \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is an $n \times n$ complex matrix for each $x \in [0,\beta]$.

I am wondering what kind of conditions I need to impose on $B$ in order for a non-trivial solution $p \in C^\infty([0,\beta],U(n))$ to 
$$
Dp = 0 \; , \quad p(0) = I
$$
to exist. (Here $U(n)$ denotes unitary $n \times n$ matrices)

For example if we take $n=1$ and $U=I$ then $Dp = 0$ is equivalent to 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\log p = B. 
$$
(For this to make sense we need to ensure that we can choose a branch cut for $\log$)

Then 
$$
p(x) = \exp({\int_0^x B(u) du}) 
$$

In this elementary case it seems we don't need to impose any restrictions on $B$ but I am wondering how this would generalize to the higher dimensional case.